# Elasticsearch.Net and NEST to search both for a string and array of tags

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-net

Having a data like this: `{ "id" : 22, "name" : "test", "tagIds" : [ 2, 35, 56, 59 ] }`, how is it possible to search for both **name** and **tags**?

Using following query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,  
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tagIds": [
        35
      ]
    },  
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "test",
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Gets this parsing exception: `[terms] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`

How to write this correctly in fluent nest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) for combining multiple queries. Hence, your query should look like below:

```
{   
    "from": 0,  
    "size": 100,     
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "tagIds": [
                            35
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "test",
                        "fields": [
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work if tagIds was empty, so I changed **must-terms** to **should-term**.

Comment: If you change it to should-term, the logic changes. Now the logic becomes (tags IN [35] OR name = test) instead of (tags IN [35] AND name = test). Is that what you want?

Comment: Then how can I handle if ```tags``` was empty but ```name``` wasn't?

Comment: This you have to do in the client code itself; Elasticsearch can't help you here much. If `tags` was empty, then do not even create the query with `tags`, just create the query with `name` field.